The Visual Studio Code is showing falls error on all files
The VSCode (Insider) is showing false errors on every file even thought the code is correct:


By the way, I didn't have this problem on normal VSCode but only when I switched to VSCode Insider.

Insider builds are expected to have problems, and it is hoped that you will report those problems to Microsoft.

If you are only seeing this on Insider, that indicates it is likely a bug with VSCode and not something you can easily fix yourself.
Insider builds are inherently more likely to have bugs or unstable code. If this issue bothers you, it's probably best to switch to stable VSCode.
If you can find consistent reproduction steps, consider a bug report.

I will report it and Thank you

@guilty link please

If you are only seeing this on Insider, that indicates it is likely a bug with VSCode and not something you can easily fix yourself.
https://youtu.be/OZWkwAYuEvU?si=79ZAkSGdHfebq4Ml

This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post; instead, provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker. - From Review
